# recover commits that didn’t exist locally without direct access to the Git repository

Tags: git

I was reading a book which says:

**the reflog isn’t pushed remotely, so if you unintentionally rewrite history on the remote branch, there’s no way to recover commits you didn’t have
locally without direct access to the Git repository on the server. For this reason, you should be careful when rewriting remote branches.**

I'm a little bit confused, because it seems that we can still recover commits if we have direct access to the Git repository on the server.

could anyone give a scenario that how we can recover commit in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can unintentionally rewrite remote history eg. by forcing a push. Let's say you are forcing a push containing completely different history than visible on your remote branch. If you rewrite that history, you cannot access the previous history on the remote, so you cannot recover a commit if it is not listed in the history. This is why you should be careful while rewriting history on a remote branch. Additionally there are no reference logs on a remote repository (as described in your book, reflog isn't pushed to a remote), so you cannot use reflog to go back to your commit if you do not have it locally.